# How to derive values from an array using the index value

Tags: arrays, netlogo

I am trying to use an array in NetLogo to store my images and call the values using their index. Looks like I am getting stuck with common manner of accessing the array's value via arrayName[0].

How do I do that in NetLogo? googling doesn't seem to have the answer.

My array:

```
let imgArray ["easy1.png" "easy2.png" "easy3.png" "easy4.png" "easy5.png"]
```

I am trying to fix the image in the following manner:

```
clear-drawing import-drawing imgArray[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [item](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item):

```
item 1 imgArray
```

Note that it's zero-indexed, so the first item is `item 0 imgArray`, though `first imgArray` is more idiomatic.

Also, arrays in NetLogo are called lists.